# FirebaseListAdapter<> Updated to a newer version of Firebase 4+

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I followed the [following tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/get-started-with-firebase-for-android--cms-27248)
and Android Studio broke while I was running the code from `MainActivity.java`.

The main sections of the code:

**build.gradle** (Module:app)

```
    android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.samcompany.samichatting2"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }  ...                                                                            
      dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
   implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.3.0'
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5"
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.3.0'
}
```

**build.gradle** (Project:30dec2018_update1)

```
...
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
...
```

In `MainActivity.java`this part of the code is the main issue:

```
private void displayChatMessages() {
        ListView listOfMessages = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_of_messages);
        Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("chats");
        FirebaseListOptions<ChatMessage> options = new FirebaseListOptions.Builder<ChatMessage>()
                .setQuery(query, ChatMessage.class)
                .build();
        FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage> adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage>(options) {...}};
```

I saw some links about this theme but no one helped me because now the Firebase version is 4+.

**Why does this section code break my app even if the app has no error?**

This is the stack trace:

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.samcompany.samichatting2, PID: 5617
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.samcompany.samichatting2/com.samcompany.samichatting2.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Layout cannot be null. Call setLayout.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2502)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1348)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5648)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Layout cannot be null. Call setLayout.
        at com.firebase.ui.common.Preconditions.assertNonNull(Preconditions.java:27)
        at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseListOptions$Builder.build(FirebaseListOptions.java:162)
        at com.samcompany.samichatting2.MainActivity.displayChatMessages(MainActivity.java:138)
        at com.samcompany.samichatting2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:54)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6269)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2502) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1348) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5648) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

ChatMessage.Java

```
package com.samcompany.samichatting2;
import java.util.Date;

public class ChatMessage {

    private String messageText;
    private String messageUser;
    private long messageTime;

    public ChatMessage(String messageText, String messageUser) {
        this.messageText = messageText;
        this.messageUser = messageUser;

        // Initialize to current time
        messageTime = new Date().getTime();
    }

    public ChatMessage(){

    }

    public String getMessageText() {
        return messageText;
    }

    public void setMessageText(String messageText) {
        this.messageText = messageText;
    }

    public String getMessageUser() {
        return messageUser;
    }

    public void setMessageUser(String messageUser) {
        this.messageUser = messageUser;
    }

    public long getMessageTime() {
        return messageTime;
    }

    public void setMessageTime(long messageTime) {
        this.messageTime = messageTime;
    }
}
```

MainActivity.Java

```
package com.samcompany.samichatting2;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.firebase.ui.auth.AuthUI;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseListOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseListAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage> adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() == null) {
            // Start sign in/sign up activity
            startActivityForResult(
                    AuthUI.getInstance()
                            .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                            .build(),
                    SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE
            );
        } else {
            // User is already signed in. Therefore, display
            // a welcome Toast
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "Welcome " + FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
                            .getCurrentUser()
                            .getDisplayName(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();

            // Load chat room contents
            displayChatMessages();
        }
        FloatingActionButton fab =
                (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab);

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                EditText input = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input);

                // Read the input field and push a new instance
                // of ChatMessage to the Firebase database
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                        .getReference()
                        .push()
                        .setValue(new ChatMessage(input.getText().toString(),
                                FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
                                        .getCurrentUser()
                                        .getDisplayName())
                        );

                // Clear the input
                input.setText("");
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                    Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Toast.makeText(this,
                        "Successfully signed in. Welcome!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
                displayChatMessages();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this,
                        "We couldn't sign you in. Please try again later.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();

                // Close the app
                finish();
            }
        }

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(item.getItemId() == R.id.menu_sign_out) {
            AuthUI.getInstance().signOut(this)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                    "You have been signed out.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();

                            // Close activity
                            finish();
                        }
                    });
        }
        return true;
    }


    //Code issues
    private void displayChatMessages() {
        ListView listOfMessages = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_of_messages);
        Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("chats");
        FirebaseListOptions<ChatMessage> options = new FirebaseListOptions.Builder<ChatMessage>()
                .setQuery(query, ChatMessage.class)
                .build();
        FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage> adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void populateView(View v, ChatMessage model, int position) {
                // Get references to the views of message.xml
                TextView messageText = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
                TextView messageUser = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.message_user);
                TextView messageTime = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.message_time);
                // Set their text
                messageText.setText(model.getMessageText());
                messageUser.setText(model.getMessageUser());
                messageTime.setText(DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy (HH:mm:ss)",
                        model.getMessageTime()));
            }
        };

        listOfMessages.setAdapter(adapter); //Stop here
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.samcompany.samichatting2.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_send_black_24dp"
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:tint="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        app:fabSize="mini" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/fab"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Input"
            android:id="@+id/input"
            />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_above="@id/fab"
        android:dividerHeight="16dp"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:id="@+id/list_of_messages"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

message.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/message_user"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/message_user"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:id="@+id/message_time" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/message_user"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/message_text"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**I use RemixOS as an emulator to run the app.**
The project has created with API17.
I noticed that the main issue was the code inside `private void displayChatMessages()`. When I delete the code from there the app running but it does not display messages.

Comment: What is the problem with that code?

Comment: Please edit your question with the link under it and add all relevant information there. Don't forget to include the actual error message, and the complete stack trace, as right now I'm still not sure what's going wrong. Also: don't post screenshots of textual content, but add it as plain text and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to make it look good.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thank you for your notice! I updated the first link with the stack trace.

Comment: As the error message says, you need to call `setLayout(...)` on `FirebaseListOptions.Builder` to that FirebaseUI knows what layout XML to inflate for each node.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @FrankvanPuffelen ! I solved this issue. I can send the messages and they appear in the app's view but now I would like to send me messages another user not only me.